# Primefaces datatable not editing

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to make editable primefaces datatable. I'm using http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf. All database table data showing up, but then I trying to edit data in a table I'm getting following error:

/index.xhtml @23,90 listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'tableBean' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @23,90 listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'tableBean' resolved to null

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title>index.xhtml</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">  

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

<p:dataTable var="u" value="#{logonTest.userList}" id="carList" editable="true">  

    <f:facet name="header">  
        In-Cell Editing  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages" />  

    <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:30%">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{u.name}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{u.name}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Surname" style="width:20%">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{u.surname}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{u.surname}" style="width:100%" />  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>
```

**TableBean.java**

```
   public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(" Edited", ((User) event.getObject()).getName());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(" Cancelled", ((User) event.getObject()).getName());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }
```

Comment: The managed bean `tableBean` is not instanciated yet, which means no property/method can be found. Show us the header of this bean.

Comment: What Omar said, check that you have the correct annotations @ViewScoped (assuming you want view and more importantly @ManagedBean)